# Having trouble declaring two separate workbooks- getting .a type mismatch error when I do so

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing code to record the current date and count the number of rows in a separate workbook. The former workbook is Sales and the latter is called tracker (files names).
I want to count the rows in sales, and print it (along with the date) in the tracker workbook.
This is the code I've been using:

```
Sub StoreDate()
    Dim SalesWb As Workbook, TrackerWb As Workbook
    Set SalesWb = "Sales" & ".xlsm"
    Set TrackerWb = "Tracker" & ".xlsm"

    Dim SalesWs As Worksheet, TrackerWs As Worksheet
    Set SalesWs = SalesWb("Data")
    Set TrackerWs = TrackerWb("Tracker")

    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim Date1 As Long

    LDate = Date
    last_row = SalesWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    TrackerWs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = last_row
    TrackerWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = LDate
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you have to make it `Set TrackerWs = TrackerWb.Sheets("Tracker")` ?

Comment: Also that value may not be a number. Did you mean to grab the `Row`?

Comment: If that `Value` is a decimal,it will also through a type error.

Comment: I'm getting the error on line 3. It doesn't like: Set SalesWb = "Sales" & ".xlsm"

Comment: Oh yeah, that's no good either. Is the workbook already open or are you trying to open it with the macro?

Comment: If it's open, use this code instead:  `Set SalesWb = Workbooks("Sales")`

Comment: I want to open it using the code. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: and even with it open that code (Set SalesWb = Workbooks("Sales")) still doesn't work unfortunately. Now getting error 438.

Comment: It will work. Make sure it's spelled exactly like the file name. No parenthesis around it.

Comment: So like this: Set SalesWb = Worksbooks ("Sales")  for workbook and SalesWs = SalesWb ("Data") for the sheet?

Comment: yea. I think you need `set` for both. Honestly just google/youtube set a workbook to a variable and you'll figure it out.

Comment: Which workbook contains the code? If e.g. "Tracker" does, then you will reference it with `Set TrackerWb = ThisWorkbook` not caring about its name. If a workbook is not open, the safest way to open it is by specifying its path e.g., `Set SalesWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Sales.xlsm")`. To ensure the results written one next to each other, you could do: `Dim tCell As Range: Set tCell = TrackerWs.Range("A" & TrackerWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) : tCell.Value = LDate : tCell.Offset(, 1).Value = last_row`, or the last one a little more flexible: `tCell.EntireRow.Columns("B").Value = last_row`

Answer (score 0):

Made a few corrections to your syntax:

```
Sub StoreDate()
    
Dim SalesWb As Workbook, TrackerWb As Workbook
Dim SalesWs As Worksheet, TrackerWs As Worksheet
Dim last_row As Long
Dim Date1 As string

'Open Workbooks
Set SalesWb = workbooks.open("Sales" & ".xlsm")
Set TrackerWb = workbooks.open("Tracker" & ".xlsm")

'reference worksheets
Set SalesWs = SalesWb.worksheets("Data")
Set TrackerWs = TrackerWb.worksheets("Tracker")

LDate = Date  'get system data into string
last_row = SalesWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
TrackerWs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = last_row
TrackerWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = LDate

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
SalesWb.close
TrackerWb.close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy to Another Workbook

- It is assumed that the following is located in a standard module (e.g. `Module1`) in the (open) `Tracker.xlsm` workbook. If it is located in a third workbook, then you'll need to reference the `Tracker` workbook in the way the `Sales` workbook is being referenced (`...Workbooks.Open(...)`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub StoreDataReadable()
    
    ' Sales: Read the last row into a variable.
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Sales.xlsm")
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Data")
    
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' was only read from
    
    ' Tracker: Write current date and 'slRow'.
    
    Dim twb As Workbook: Set twb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = twb.Worksheets("Tracker")
    
    Dim tCell As Range
    Set tCell = tws.Cells(tws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    tCell.EntireRow.Columns("A").Value = Date ' tCell.Value = Date
    tCell.EntireRow.Columns("B").Value = slRow ' tCell.Offset(, 1).Value = slRow
    
    'twb.Save
    
    MsgBox "Data and last row stored.", vbInformation, "Store Data"
    
End Sub

Sub StoreDataMaintainable()
    
    ' Sales
    Const sPath As String = "C:\Test\Sales.xlsm"
    Const sName As String = "Data"
    Const slrCol As String = "A"
    ' Tracker
    Const tName As String = "Tracker"
    Const tlrCol As String = "A"
    Const tDateCol As String = "A"
    Const tRowCol As String = "B"
    
    ' Sales: Read the last row into a variable.
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sPath)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, slrCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' was only read from
    
    ' Tracker: Write current date and 'slRow'.
    
    Dim twb As Workbook: Set twb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = twb.Worksheets(tName)
    
    Dim tCell As Range
    Set tCell = tws.Cells(tws.Rows.Count, tlrCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    tCell.EntireRow.Columns(tDateCol).Value = Date
    tCell.EntireRow.Columns(tRowCol).Value = slRow
    
    'twb.Save
    
    MsgBox "Data and last row stored.", vbInformation, "Store Data"
    
End Sub
```